# connection timed out when express endpoints are called outside of the local machine

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, express, xmlhttprequest

So I have an mysql database running on my server which is accessed using express and node. The problem I am having is that when I call an express endpoint from my browser the connection times out. However, if I `wget ipaddress:3030/matches/` from the server itself the data is returned correctly.

Why can I not access the endpoint from my browser? Thank you!

This is what my express `dbconnect.js` looks like

```
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
    //DB properies..
    host: "localhost",
    user: "admin",
    password: "******",
    socketPath:"/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock",
    database: "conp2"
});

var port = 3030;
connection.connect(function (error) {       //connect to database
    if (!!error){
        console.log(error);
        console.log("Error Connecting to database");
    } else {
        console.log("Connected to port:" + port);
    }
});

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
    next();
});

app.get("/matches", function (req,res) {
    res.send("example");
}

app.listen(port);
```

In my html page this is how I call the endpoint:

```
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
     xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {                                                         
         if (xhttp.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE && xhttp.status == 200) {
             //here I manipulate the data received
             console.log(this.responseText);                                                         
             tallier.scoreparser(this.responseText);
          }
     };
xhttp.open("GET", "http://localhost:3030/matches", true);
xhttp.send();
```

Comment: Did you tried with `127.0.0.1` instead of localhost in your `xhttp.open` call?

Comment: yes I have tried that and it does not work but usually in the http.open call I have the servers address